# Sending Multiple values from `model` to `template.hbs` - the ember way

Tags: ember.js

I am looking the correct `ember` recommendation approach to group my data values before i send to template.

Because I have the data in 2 different arrays.

I don't want to keep no.of iterators across the app. so I would like to group the data within newly creating/created array or the correct way ember recommends. any one help me?

my model : ( sample )

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(){
    return {
        "data" : {
        "group" : [{"group":"newGroup"}, {"group":"oldGroup"}],
        "details" : [{"name":"arif","age":"3"},                 {"name":"afi","age":"2"}]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

my hbs : /*{{data.data.group}} - how to show this? by equal array value?*/

```
{{#each model.data.details as |data| }}
    <li>{{data.data.group}} {{data.name}} -- {{data.age}} </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

[Live Demo](https://ember-twiddle.com/b7b835285e07f24d8f2b1ed0d6fdf754?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the `group` array with the current index of the `details` array:

```
{{#each model.data.details as |data index| }}
    <li>{{get this (concat "model.data.group." index ".group")}} {{data.name}} -- {{data.age}} </li>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand it correctly, that you want to show the corresponding group to the details data set? If so, the way you want to show the group is not working because there is no `model.data.details.data.group` as you try to access right now. Remember, your data in your each loop is a "reference" to the `model.data.details`

I would highly recommend, that you restructure your data set so that there is a connection between the group and the details. Right now, I can tell if there is one... .

Consider this as a new data structure:

```
{
  data: {
    groups: {
      newGroup: {
        name: "arif",
        age: 3
      },
      oldGroup: {
        name: "afi",
        age: 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can iterate over this structure like this

```
{{#each-in data.groups as |groupName details|}}
  {{#each details as |data|}}
    {{groupName}} {{data.name}} - {{data.age}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each-in}}
```

Also as a side node, it seems to me, that you want to use this data multiple times in your app. If this is true, consider using a [service](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/applications/services/) for that and reuse the service in every component you want to access it.
In your components js file you can than setup a computed property that accesses the data from your service.

Comment: I don't have the rights to restructure my data. ( twiddle is sample ) and I have no.of iteration stuff do show in hbs. how to merge necessary values to handle easly? can you consider this? ( don't thing about my twiddle sample )

Comment: What is the connection between the details and the group? Only the index of the array?

Comment: at present yes. But some pages contains no.of datas are connected each.

Comment: What do you mean with your 2nd sentence? Can you please show an example in your post?

Comment: Nothing but mixing data to display